# How to add the html table into DocuSign Document with the help of docusign php api?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on one module where after records create into SQL, I have to show that records on DocuSign Document into Table but I am not able to show the HTML table data into DocuSign Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your HTML document and then send it to DocuSign as part of the envelope definition.

This is demonstrated in the PHP JWT example. See the [send_envelope.php](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt/blob/master/lib/send_envelope.php) file.